# Are SSDs reliable for developers?

Tags: ssd

I see that data in SSDs can be written a limited number of times and then it dies.
**My concern is that for how long SSD can be used by developers ** knowing that developers heavily use system cresting multiple VMs uding bulky softwares etc.

Also out of 3 types of SSD which are SLC, eMLC and MLC in market MLC type  SSD are generally available which have shortest lifespan.

Comment: You can write hundreds of GBs a day and the typical SSD will last for years.

Comment: I see that a in a typical MLC based SSD each blick can be written for almost 10k times vs 50k times in SLC based SSD, so I think that SSD can die soon.

Comment: Intel says differently: https://superuser.com/questions/203917/lifetime-of-mlc-ssd

Comment: This question seems like it would be a better fit in the [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) SE site.

Comment: Anyone using Spotify [could have been writing hundreds of GBs every day without even knowing it](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/11/for-five-months-spotify-has-badly-abused-users-storage-drives/). But all that does not really matter if one creates backups. Not a very new idea...! ;-) And the performance gain, both while compiling and while listening to Spotify all day long, surely makes up for any early replacement.

Comment: The question is off topic but I think the down votes are unfair

Comment: @dave thanks, It may be off topic but not everyone knows if particular topic belongs to particular site, I never downvoted any question in last 4 years

Comment: It's actually defined in the help section. The question is opinion based. One developers need is different to the next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have to worry about ssd's dying on you if you buy the latest ssds because of wear.

They will easily last over 5 years for most development use, but you will probably want to replace your entire system before that because of newer specs in computers, ssds and so on.

SLC are single cell and most resilient, however, the MLC market has also matured quite a bit and they are also very stable. And the same goes for TLC.

For your purpose all should work fine.

If you getting this for a production DB server that overwrites the drive multiple times a day then you might want to go for enterprise SLC ssd drives which can sustain higher workloads.

Lifespan (Highes to lowest) - SLC >> MLC >> TLC

You get the most reliability by backing up your data and using replication (software raid, etc)

Comment: Can you tell that how many write cycle can a typical 100 $ 250 gb SSD can handle?, I am just looking for an idea, needs not to be very specific.

Comment: @codemirror Read the datasheet on the specific SSD your interested in.  Your question is currently way to braid to answer

Comment: As @Ramhound suggested it is too broad to answer. But I can almost guarantee for your use case that you wont be breaking a SSD due to excessive writes.  With data of over 1000 SSDs in operation I can ask you to not worry about the nitty gritty and just get on with it. The cost of your time is more expensive than savings you would make comparing different SSDs. Just get a samsung or intel latest version drive and get on with your work. If you are not going to deploy a 1000 SSDs for intensive server workloads, you would be fine,

Comment: Even when you reach your maximum amount of writes, you can still read the data, and if the SSD is the only copy of your data then shame on you.

Comment: @Ramhound agreed :)

Answer (score 4):

A typical MLC SSD [lasts for years](http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead) under normal use. Even TLC SSDs do! Keep in mind: if you work, it’s probably something like 8 hours a day. That’s 1/3 of 24 hours.

Also, most SSDs have excellent durability self-reporting (via SMART), so you can tell when it’ll fail and get a replacement if needed.

If you like HDD noise, slowness, latency or whatever, you can keep using HDDs of course. They’ll continue to be around, because they’re large. Software development *extremely* profits from SSDs’ low latency. You want that. And you will *never* go back.